# Can't load image from Parse - Swift dynamic cast failed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to pull a user's image from Parse in my View Controller. However, whenever I run the app, it crashes with this error:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x106742620:  pushq  %rbp
0x106742621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x106742624:  pushq  %rbx
0x106742625:  pushq  %rax
0x106742626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x106742629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x10674262c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x10674262e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x106742631:  je     0x10674264c               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x106742633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x10674263a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x10674263d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x106742640:  callq  0x1067451ca               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x106742645:  testb  %al, %al
0x106742647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x10674264a:  je     0x106742653               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x10674264c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x106742650:  popq   %rbx
0x106742651:  popq   %rbp
0x106742652:  retq   
0x106742653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10674265a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x106742661:  int3   
0x106742662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I know the image exists and the user attribute is correctly called "image" in Parse. The user object comes from a segue from the previous screen. The user first name label displays correctly when I comment out the image code so I know the user object is valid.

If I set a breakpoint where the app seems to crash `let userImageFile = user?["image"] as PFFile`, I can hover over userImageFile with my mouse pointer and it shows "ObjectiveC.NSObject(NSObject)". Once I continue past the breakpoint the app crashes with the error above.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var timer: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!

    var user: PFUser?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userName.text = user?["first_name"] as String?

        let userImageFile = user?["image"] as PFFile

        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil{

                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                    self.userImage.image = image

                } else {

                    println(error)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Any ideas? I think it must have something to do with userImageFile being an ObjectiveC NSObject but I'm not sure what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if let user = user{
      userName.text = user["first_name"] as? String

      if let userImageFile = user["image"] as? PFFile{
         userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { imageData, error in
            if error == nil{
               let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
               self.userImage.image = image
            } else {
               println(error)
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also it is good practice to name `IBOutlet`s in such a way that the underlying type will be clear. For example: 
userName -> userNameLabel 
timer -> timerLabel and etc.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks! The app no longer crashes, but the image is blank. It doesn't seem to pull the image from Parse. I'm trying to step through the code now to see why it's not pulling the image. After placing some breakpoints in that closure, it seems like the app gets hung up on `if let userImageFile = user["image"] as? PFFile` and doesn't continue the rest of the nested code.

Comment: That means that the object stored in `user["image"]` is not a `PFFile`.

Comment: You might be right. The column in Parse shows "image(bytes)". Not sure how to get this from Parse

Comment: Maybe it is NSData object? In that case use `let image = UIImage(data: data)`

Comment: using that shows error message: "Use of unresolved identifier 'data'". I just looked at my code that added the image. It's definitely an NSData object

Comment: Try this: `if let userImageData = user["image"] as? NSData{ userImage.image = UIImage(data: userImageData) }`. Consider that creating UIImage from NSData is expensive in terms of time and may block your main thread for a while. In that case create UIImage in background thread and assign to UIImageView on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The failed cast seems to indicate that you didn't store a PFFile... or did not store anything at all...
Can you show the code that store the file in your user ?

Also you can check the content of your user in the Parse console. 
Add an extra column called "image" of type File (PFFile's name).
When you hit the breakpoint, refresh the console and check the content of the 'image' column.